# Database errors when opening

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm having trouble opening a Database.I can get the DB to open and close and grab the data that I require in a Layout class and push it to a UI fine. But i also want to open the DB in the background and read the data as well(Not at the same time as the UI). I am having trouble doing this and get a error in the Helperclass
I am calling the class like this:

```
GenerateFiringData GenData=new GenerateFiringData(); //Generate the firing data
```

and this is the class

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.util.Log;


    public class GenerateFiringData extends Activity{
DBAdapter myDb1;

public GenerateFiringData(){
    openDB();  //open database
    ..... 

}   

private void openDB() {
    myDb1 = new DBAdapter(this);
    myDb1.open();// <<<<<<<<<<problem starts here
}

private void closeDB() {
    myDb1.close();
}
    }
```

When the 'myDb1.open()' code is called  it is sent to

```
   // Open the database connection.
public DBAdapter open() {
    db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();<<<---------errors here
    return this;
}
```

What am i doing wrong??? the database code for the UI part of my project goes thew this fine and i cant figure out why

Thanks
Snow

Comment: have You initialized Your databaseHelper myDBHelper ?

Comment: This is called by the 'myDb1 = new DBAdapter(this);'                                                 public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {
 this.context = ctx;
 myDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context); is this what you mean... I'm a bit of a Green Horn at this Android stuff

Answer (score 0):

Found a work around
Call the class as an intent like similar to a opening a new layout.
Now sure if this is the 'Correct way" but it works